# apply the top navigation bar of SharePoint into my header and footer navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How can I apply the top navigation bar of SharePoint into my header and footer navigation.
so I put the Snipped code for the header and it works fine
but for the footer no way to duplicate the snipped code two time.

```
<!--MS:<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >--> 
                            <div data-name="TopNavigationNoFlyoutWithStartNode" class="nav">
                                        <!--CS: Début de l'extrait de code Navigation supérieure-->
                                        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                                        <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation ms-dialogHidden" runat="server">-->
                                            <!--PS: Début de l'aperçu en mode lecture seule (ne pas modifier)--><!--PE: Fin de l'aperçu en lecture seule-->
                                            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
                                            <a name="startNavigation">
                                            </a>
                                            <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">-->
                                                <!--MS:<SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="topSiteMap" AccessKey="&#60;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&#62;" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" AdjustForShowStartingNode="false" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="">--><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Collaboration</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/perso"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Perso</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Pages/Annuaire.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Annuaire</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Applications Métier"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Applications Métier</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" title="Le centre de recherche affiche les résultats de la recherche" href="http://srvdev:8080/SearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Recherche</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" title="Site Web de l'annuaire de sites" href="http://srvdev:8080/SiteDirectory/Pages/category.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Sites</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/ATBLEARN"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">ATB eLearning</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Page not found</span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">ATB News Net</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/amicale"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Amicale</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Collaboration/Pages/default.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Collaboration</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/perso"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Perso</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Pages/Annuaire.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Annuaire</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Applications Métier"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Page not found</span></span></a>
                                                <!--ME:</SharePoint:AspMenu>-->
                                            <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
                                            <!--PS: Début de l'aperçu en mode lecture seule (ne pas modifier)--><!--PE: Fin de l'aperçu en lecture seule-->
                                        <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
                                        <!--CE: Fin de l'extrait de code Navigation supérieure-->
                                    </div>                                <!--ME:</asp:content>-->
```

So if i use :
1-

```
 <!--MS:<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >-->
```

> error: we cant found close tab

2- with out "`<!--MS and ME`"

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
```

> error xml

3- using PalceHolder :

```
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Footer" runat="server">-->
```

> error:PlaceHolderTopNavBar is alredy in use

So any idea.

Answer (score 1):

There cant be two `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` tags with the same ID. So try calling your `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` in the footer PlaceHolderTopNavBarFooter for example.

```
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="**PlaceHolderTopNavBar**" runat="server">-->
                                                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="topSiteMap" AccessKey="&#60;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&#62;" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" AdjustForShowStartingNode="false" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="">--><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Collaboration</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/perso"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Perso</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Pages/Annuaire.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Annuaire</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Applications Métier"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Applications Métier</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" title="Le centre de recherche affiche les résultats de la recherche" href="http://srvdev:8080/SearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Recherche</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" title="Site Web de l'annuaire de sites" href="http://srvdev:8080/SiteDirectory/Pages/category.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Sites</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/ATBLEARN"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">ATB eLearning</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Page not found</span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">ATB News Net</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/amicale"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Amicale</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Collaboration/Pages/default.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Collaboration</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/perso"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Perso</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Pages/Annuaire.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Annuaire</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="http://srvdev:8080/Applications Métier"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Page not found</span></span></a>
                                                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:AspMenu>-->
                                                <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed to this :

`AspMenu ID="FooterNavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="footerSiteMap"`

I added the navigation footer using this:

```
 <!--MS:<asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ID="footerSiteMap" runat="server" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002">-->
                                                        <!--ME:</asp:SiteMapDataSource>-->


                                <!--MS:<SharePoint:AspMenu ID="FooterNavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="footerSiteMap" AccessKey="&#60;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&#62;" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" AdjustForShowStartingNode="false" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="">-->href="http://srvdev:8080/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Page not found</span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul></div><!--PE: Fin de l'aperçu en lecture seule-->
                :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:AspMenu>-->
```

and it works